# Что значит отмечать друзей в API Taggable Friends от Facebook?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-api, facebooksdk

Фейсбук сейчас не дает доступа к полному списку друзей и предлагает как альтернативу использовать `API Taggable Friends`

на офф написано так

> В версии 2.0 список друзей, не использующих ваше приложение, недоступен. Однако вы можете предоставить людям возможность отмечать друзей с помощью API Taggable Friends.

Что значит предоставить возможность отмечать друзей?

Answer (score 1):

Те user-ы в вашем friend-list которые позволяют вам отмечать их на фотографиях, записях, отмечать в комметариях, 

 `Example: @userName`
Зачастую вы получите весь список друзей так как по умолчанию они позволяют вам отмечать их.

Можете ознокомиться ближе с этим вопросом тут [Facebook thread](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=700455260039556)

Comment: Ага понял, но почему тогда сам фейсбук предлагает этот способ как альтернативу стандартному (бывшему) списку друзей, если я так понимаю, что кроме имени ничего получить этим способом нельзя...

Comment: @Aleksey Timoshchenko Тут все что вам надо http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u

Comment: я уже читал этот пост, но мой вопрос был в другом...